# How to send private message with socket io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am pretty confused with socket io that How Should I able to send private message

Approach One

```
socket.emit(`privateMessage:${req.user._id}`, 'someones Private message to User')
```

and in client I am receiving this message with user id

Approach Two

```
socket.to(socketID).emit(`privateMessage`, 'someones Private message to User')
```

I don't know which is standard way to do this and I am also using redis pub sub.I am pretty much confused how to tie up these in standard architecture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the `socket` object for the target user, then to send a message just to that user, you should use:

```
socket.emit(...)
```

If you don't have the `socket` object for the target user, but do have the socketID for that user, then you can use:

```
io.to(socketID).emit(...)
```

There's really no reason to use `socket.to(socketID)` where socketID is the id of `socket` because you already have the `socket` object for the target user so `socket.emit()` is more direct and probably slightly faster.

Comment: Great !! Thanks But one question ```socket``` object you referring to the user id or some thing related to user Right ?

Comment: @Nane - When a user connects, they get a socket object - an actual Javascript object that represents the connection.  That is presented to you in `io.on('connection, function(socket) {});` when they connect.  I'm saying that if you already have the socket object for the target user (because you saved it or because you got some other message from that socket or however you got it), you can just use `socket.emit()`.  If not, you can ask the socket.io library to look it up for you with `io.to(socketID).emit()`.